# google places auto complete not working on redirect

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, google-places-api, reload

I have 2 pages, a main page and a secondary. And in both the pages I have a form with the auto complete integrated.

In the main page after I choose a place(Auto complete works here) and click the submit button i get redirected to the secondary page, where the results get displayed.

When I use the form in this secondary page the auto complete doesn't work. But if I reload the page, it works.

I have tried `$route.reload`, `$location.path($location.path())` etc, but that is not helping. Only `location.reload()` works, and the data stored in the services is getting reset when I use this.

Comment: is it possible to add plunkr please?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "the auto complete doesn't work"?  Do any errors get logged to the JS console?

Comment: The console shows no errors. But i have figured it out. I will post the solution here soon.

Comment: @MukundGandlur, It's been a while, but I have ran into the same problem. Could you share your solution?

Comment: I think i replaced routeProvider with stateprovider and did a $state.reload(); on the coming to the page.